# How to use a pre-trained object detection in tensorflow?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

How can I use the weights of a pre-trained network in my tensorflow project?
I know some theory information about this but no information about coding in tensorflow.

Comment: This is a very broad question. For the second part, search 'transfer learning'.

Comment: Object detection performance is not measured by accuracy but by mAP, so your  first question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As been pointed out by @Matias Valdenegro in the comments, your first question does not make sense. For your second question however, there are multiple ways to do so. The term that you're searching for is Transfer Learning (TL). TL means transferring the "knowledge" (basically it's just the weights) from a pre-trained model into your model. Now there are several types of TL.

1) **You transfer the entire weights from a pre-trained model into your model and use that as a starting point to train your network.**

- This is done in a situation where you now have extra data to train your model but you don't want to start over the training again. Therefore you just load the weights from your previous model and resume the training.

**2) You transfer only some of the weights from a pre-trained model into your new model.**

- This is done in a situation where you have a model trained to classify between, say, 5 classes of objects. Now, you want to add/remove a class. You don't have to re-train the whole network from the start if the new class that you're adding has somewhat similar features with (an) existing class(es). Therefore, you build another model with the same exact architecture as your previous model except the fully-connected layers where now you have different output size. In this case, you'll want to load the weights of the convolutional layers from the previous model and freeze them while only re-train the fully-connected layers.

To perform these in Tensorflow,

1) The first type of TL can be performed by creating a model with the same exact architecture as the previous model and simply loading the model using ***tf.train.Saver().restore()*** module and continue the training.

2) The second type of TL can be performed by creating a model with the same exact architecture for the **parts where you want to retain the weights** and then specify the name of the weights in which you want to load from the previous pre-trained weights. You can use the parameter ***"trainable=False"*** to prevent Tensorflow from updating them.

I hope this helps.